# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH)

Tags: php

Why is this code causing a syntax error? Why can't I catch the exception?

```
protected function RunQuery($sql) {
    $pdo = $this->conn;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    if($stmt) {
        $stmt->execute($sql);
    } else {
        print_r("Unable to prepare the query");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as the error states, you have an unexpected `catch` statement.  Why is that statement there?

Comment: `catch` always works with `try`, with the syntax `try{ /*code*/ }catch(Exception $e){ /*code*/ }`. see http://php.net/manual/fr/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a try block before you can add a catch block. You will need to change your code to something like this:

```
protected function RunQuery ($sql) { 

    $pdo = $this->conn;

    try
    {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->execute($sql);
        } else {
            print_r("Unable to prepare the query");
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

More information about try & catch and how to work with exceptions can be found in the [php documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Answer (score -3):

Seems like you are missing an '}' on the line above catch.

Comment: Moving the `catch` statement outside the function would also be "unexpected" to the parser.

Comment: the catch is inside the function